# Least verbose way of calling Method on each object in two lists with a matching element

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists that are populated from two different sources

```
List<MyObject> updatedObjs;
List<MyObject> currentObjs;
```

All of the elements in updatedObjs have the same string identifier as an element within the currentObjs list. This string Identifier can be simply accessed by getID() which returns a String.

What I would like to do is to find each match in the currentObjs list for each element in updatedObjs and then call a method passing the matching objects from both lists in.

I have figured out code for finding the match in both lists:

```
        updatedObjs.stream().filter(updatedObj -> currentObjs.stream().anyMatch(currentObj -> updatedObj.getID().equals(currentObj.getID()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this will just find the matches...is there any way of calling anyMatch and then calling a method on both matching objects?

So I want to called a method like `myMethod(currentObj, updatedObj);`

I know I can do this with nested for loops but I am looking for a more elegant solution if one exists. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need it:

```
  updatedObjs.forEach(s -> currentObjs.stream().filter(s1 -> s.getId().equals(s2.getId)).forEach(s1 -> yourMethod(s, s1)));
```

Comment: But I want to call a method on the matching elements from both lists

myMethod(updatedObj, currentObj);

Comment: Cool! I'm guessing I need to override the equals method of the class to just check the identifiers are equal? For the s::equals stuff to work

Comment: See it one more time, please

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to create a Map whose key is the id and whose values are all the objects from each list that have that key. Then iterate over the entries in the map and call your myMethod() on each list that has more than 1 entry.

```
List<MyObj> updatedObjs = new ArrayList<>(); // assuming this has values
List<MyObj> currentObjs = new ArrayList<>(); // assuming this has values

List<MyObj> allObjs = new ArrayList( updatedObjs ); // create new list with references to the objects in updatedObjs
allObjs.addAll( currentObjs ); // add everything from currentObjs to our new list

// map of id -> list of all elements with that id
Map<String,List<MyObj>> idMap = allObjs
        .stream()
        .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( obj -> obj.getID() ) );
```

Now there's two different approaches below to calling the method

```
// you could stream the entry set, filter down to only entries with more than one value in the list and run the method on each
idMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter( ( mapEntry ) -> mapEntry.getValue().size() > 1 )
        .forEach( mapEntry -> mapEntry.getValue().forEach( obj -> obj.getID() ) );

// I prefer a for-loop for this instead of streaming the entry set because it is a lot easier to read
for ( Map.Entry<String,List<MyObj>> entry : idMap.entrySet() ) { // iterate each entry
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<MyObj> value = entry.getValue();

    if ( value.size() > 1 ) {
        // has more than one entry with the given key, so run myMethod() on each
        value.forEach( obj -> obj.getID() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By iterating over the first collection then the second, you're basically having an expensive algorithm `O(n²)`

You might want to consider something more straight forward like having a `Map<String, List<MyObj>>`

This hereunder is `O(n)`

```
Map<String, List<MyObj>> map = updatedObjs.stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObj::getId));

currentObjs.forEach(obj -> map.get(obj.getId).add(obj)); // No Stream

map.forEach((k, v) -> myMethod(v.get(1), v.get(0));
```

That out of the way, the fact that you have two lists maintaining the state of the same entity is probably a bad idea. You should probably rethink your design from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

```
void perform(List<MyObject> currentObjects, List<MyObject> updatedObjects) {
    Map<String, MyObject> currentObjById = currentObjects.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getID, Function.identity()));

    Map<String, MyObject> updatedObjById = updatedObjects.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getID, Function.identity()));

    for (Map.Entry<String, MyObject> entry : currentObjById.entrySet()) {
        MyObject updatedObj = updatedObjById.get(entry.getKey());
        if (updatedObj != null) {
            myMethod(entry.getValue(), updatedObj);
        }
    }
}
```

It is more efficient than the solutions which use `anyStream`. This will work provided that you have no two elements with the same ID in each of the lists.